# how to use youtube data api v3 parameter mine

Tags: reactjs, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I want get user's playlists using youtube data api v3.

This is youtube.js

```
import axios from 'axios';
const KEY = process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY;

export default axios.create({
    baseURL: 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/',
    params: {
        part: 'snippet',
        maxResults: 5,
        key: KEY
    }
})
```

and This is Button that request user's playlist.
props is token (access_token using oauth2.0)

I want get user's playlists using youtube-api's "mine" parameter and this token.

To use mine parameter, I will have to send token.

How to send this token?

```
const LoadPlaylistButton = ({ token }) => {
    
    const loadPlaylists = async () => {
        const response = await youtube.get('/playlists', {
            params: {
                mine: true
            }
        })
        console.log("log: ", response);
    }
    
    return (
        <button onClick={loadPlaylists}>LoadPlaylist</button>
    );
};
export default LoadPlaylistButton;
```

Answer (score 0):

Using mine will require that you are authorized as a user in order to request that data.  An API key will only give you access to public data not private data

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js"></script>
<script>
  /**
   * Sample JavaScript code for youtube.playlists.list
   * See instructions for running APIs Explorer code samples locally:
   * https://developers.google.com/explorer-help/guides/code_samples#javascript
   */

  function authenticate() {
    return gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance()
        .signIn({scope: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly"})
        .then(function() { console.log("Sign-in successful"); },
              function(err) { console.error("Error signing in", err); });
  }
  function loadClient() {
    gapi.client.setApiKey("YOUR_API_KEY");
    return gapi.client.load("https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/youtube/v3/rest")
        .then(function() { console.log("GAPI client loaded for API"); },
              function(err) { console.error("Error loading GAPI client for API", err); });
  }
  // Make sure the client is loaded and sign-in is complete before calling this method.
  function execute() {
    return gapi.client.youtube.playlists.list({})
        .then(function(response) {
                // Handle the results here (response.result has the parsed body).
                console.log("Response", response);
              },
              function(err) { console.error("Execute error", err); });
  }
  gapi.load("client:auth2", function() {
    gapi.auth2.init({client_id: "YOUR_CLIENT_ID"});
  });
</script>
<button onclick="authenticate().then(loadClient)">authorize and load</button>
<button onclick="execute()">execute</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

To use mine,set Authorization in header.
Check [this](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/auth/client-side-web-apps)!

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?
  client_id=123456789-sdnjknsdkjf4skfnsdjnsfdksdkjl.apps.googleusercontent.com&
  redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Foauth2callback&
  scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube&
  response_type=token
```

```
 const res = await fetch('https://content-youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels
mine=true&part=statistics&key=asdasdasd', 
{ headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` } },);
```